# why does ctrl +tab not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do CTRL + TAB but **event.ctrlKey** is always false in this scenario. Here is my code:

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 9) 
     that._keydown(event);
```

Comment: what event you're bounding this handler? keydown ?

Comment: Seems to working for me, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xq1k0zv5/)

Comment: yes..keydown only. @shershen

Comment: ctrl+tab is tab switching key for google chrome, so your code might conflict in chrome.

Comment: Its not working@ empiric

Comment: @empiric: doesn't work for me, as suggested it does indeed conflict using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> won't work in Chrome as its own shortcuts takes precedence. As far as I am aware, there's no way around this restriction. I suggest you find an alternative combo for your shortcut. Be wary of overriding common shortcuts - that would truly annoy your users ;)

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvorhcqy/) for your own testing:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);//check the console to find out what the keyCode is for each key as you press them
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 9) {//Ctrl+Tab wont work in Chrome (its own shortcuts takes precedence). Try a different combo to prove this works. EG: Ctrl + keyCode 222 (apostrophe)
        alert("Ctrl+Tab");
        e.preventDefault(); //optionally prevent default behaviour and propagation
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```